# Reply to specific email and delete

Tags: python, imap

I want the script response for email with specific Subject and then delete that email.
The script is doing one job which is responding to the email but I'm struggling with deleting that email, I'm not sure if I'm doing it even correctly: mail.store(response[1], '+FLAGS', '\Deleted') gives an error: imaplib.error: STORE command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']

```
mail.select()
status, messages = mail.select("INBOX")
n = int(str(messages[0], 'utf-8'))
messages = int(messages[0])
for i in range(messages, messages-n,-1):
    res, msg = mail.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:

        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            # parse a bytes email into a message object
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
            Sub, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("Subject"))[0]
            if isinstance(Sub, bytes): # check the subject
                Sub=Sub.decode((encoding))
            if Sub == pat:
                fro, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
                if isinstance(fro, bytes):
                    fro = fro.decode(encoding)
                if s == 0:
                    time.sleep(180)
                    mai_load(1)

                print("From:", fro)
                send_mail(fro)
                mail.store(response[1], '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
            print("=" * 100)
```

Comment: This is *not* a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is in responses[1]? You pass the message _number_ to store, which I think is `i` in your example.

Comment: @Max I've tried 'i earlier but had an error:
TypeError: can't concat int to bytes. Now I've converted 'i' to string and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

had to change one line:

```
 mail.store(response[1], '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
```

to

```
 mail.store(str(i), '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
```